# JAVA StdDateSerializer parsing Date

Tags: java, json, date, serialization, jackson

I have custom `Date` serializer to add certain timezone.

```
public class DateDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Date> {

    public DateDeserializer() {
        this(null);
    }

    protected DateDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

    @Override
    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        Long dateString = jsonParser.getLongValue();
        Date date = new Date(dateString);
        changeTimeZone(date);
        return date;
    }
}
```

But sometimes the date doesn't come as `long` value. Sometimes it comes like `String`, for example `"2017-01-01"` and method `jsonParser.getLongValue()` fails.

Is there some way to know what kind of value `jsonParser` is holding? Because if I check `jsonParser instanceof String` or `long` it always returns `false`.

Comment: If this is Jackson, add it as a tag, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`getCurrentToken()` method](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonParser.html#getCurrentToken()) and compare with the [`JsonToken` values](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonToken.html):

```
switch (jsonParser.getCurrentToken()) {
    case VALUE_STRING:
        // get String value
        break;

    case VALUE_NUMBER_INT:
        // get int or long value
        break;
        // and so on
}
```

Or using `if`:

```
if (jsonParser.getCurrentToken() == JsonToken.VALUE_STRING) {
    // get String value
} else if (jsonParser.getCurrentToken() == JsonToken.VALUE_NUMBER_INT) {
    // get long value
}
... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

If your date is String type for example like this mask: "yyyy-MM-dd"

you can use in your deserialize method:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date date = sdf.parse(dateString);
```

Comment: It will not help as i don't get dateString value I get exception saying _Current token (VALUE_STRING) not numeric, can not use numeric value accessors_ when trying to evaluate `jsonParser.getLongValue();`